# How to Filer data between 2 Dates in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to filter data between 2 dates in Django, I am using single input box for this and I am using jquery daterangepicker for this, Please check my coed and let me know where i am mistaking.

here is my views.py file...

```
  def myview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        startdate = request.POST.get('created_on')
        enddate = request.POST.get('created_on')
        if start != None or end != None:
            result = Model.objects.filter(created_on__range=[startdate,enddate])
        else:
            print('Error')
```

here is my forms ...

```
<form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="created_on" value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <button>Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I am getting errors to filter data, I think i am mistaking in query, Please let me know how i can Solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to convert the input in date format as the form input is in text,

This might work..

```
def myview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        startdate = request.POST.get('created_on')
        enddate = request.POST.get('created_on')
        start_date = datetime.date(startdate)
        end_date = datetime.date(enddate)
        if start_date or end_date:
            result = Model.objects.filter(created_on__range=[start_date,end_date])
        else:
            print('Error')
```

Comment: it's displaying me this error...`descriptor 'date' require a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'str'`

Comment: did you import datetime? - `import datetime`

Comment: now it's displaying me this error `an integer is required (got type str)`